# Merge the web.config when publishing to the IIS (VS2010)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have a question that have been breaking my head for a good while.

I have a Web project which will not be deployed with WebDeploy, but will be with Publish option.
I need to merge the web.config, the one going from TFS till the one going to IIS, merging the information, and keeping the IIS (receiver) web.config lines if there's a conflict when uploading it.

Also to automatize the publish upload to the IIS. 
The hardest part for me is the web.config merging. Is the most important.

I've heard that this can be authomatized with the same Visual Studio 2010, but can't really find any specific answer. Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at config transformations? Take a look at the Slow Cheetah extension and see if that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your thinking of [Web Config Transformations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) but that typically is for merging config files prior to the drop, rather than merging them with what is already deployed.